# displaying leaderboard

Tags: php, google-play-services

Basically what i wish to ask:
*A game is developed for android platform, is on google store and its leader board (scores etc.) are on Google server.

Can we display the top scores from there on a webpage/website which is on a different server? Yes or No!

Comment: I haven't used it, but it looks like this is the sample project you want: https://github.com/playgameservices/web-basic-samples/tree/master/type-a-number-php

Comment: This is confusing to me, because there is both a `Google Play Services` API (appears to maybe be only for Android or iOS?), as well as a `Play Games Services` API, which has sample code for all sorts of platforms.

Comment: Let me explain:
A game has been developed in Unity for android platform and they submit their leader board scores and details on Google Play Services which shows on the Leader board of the Android phone.
Now, we have a website in PHP/MySQL and we need to dislay the game leader board (Top Scores with names) on this website. Is this possible! Please guide!
Thanks!

Comment: Basically what i wish to ask is that....

there is a game for android platform and its leader board on Google Play Services. Can we display the top scores from there on a webpage?

Comment: Maybe you should ask that as another question? (I don't honestly know if the data is shared between the two services I linked above.)